# Can program on Dev c++ rather than Microsoft visual studio ?

Tags: allegro5

I've started game programming with allegro 5 on Dev c++. But all the ebooks I've read on the net tells about doing allegro 5 game programming on Microsoft visual studio. But I have a problem, I cannot install Microsoft visual studio on my PC for some drivers problem. So my question is that can I make and RUN any game I make in Dev c++. Will that cause any problem in future. Can't game programming be done without Microsoft visual studio..?? 
Thanks 
Div's.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a C/C++ compiler. Visual Studio is not required. The allegro wiki has [instructions](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Dev-C%2B%2B) for using Allegro with Dev C++.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I'm looking forward to learn bound boxing in allegro 5.